# Perl - is object instance of class?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to check whether an object is an instance of a class? An object would be an instance of a class if it has been blessed by the class:

```
package Example;

sub new {
    $self = {};
    bless($self, shift);
    return $self;
}

############

use Example;
$exp = Example->new(); # $exp is now an 'instance' of Example
# something like instanceof($exp, Example) would return 1
```

Comment: [`perldoc -f ref`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#ref)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `blessed()` subroutine from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util) returns the name of the class that an object belongs to.

```
say blessed $exp; # prints "Example"
```

For your test, you would use something like:

```
if (blessed $exp eq 'Example') { ...}
```

If subclassing is likely to be an issue, then use `isa()` instead.

```
if ($exp->isa('Example')} { ... }
```

But that throws an error if `$exp` isn't an object, so protect the call by calling `blessed()` first.

```
if (blessed($exp) and $exp->isa('Example')) { ... }
```

`isa()` is a method on the [UNIVERSAL](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL) class and every class is a subclass of UNIVERSAL, so every object has the `isa()` method.

Comment: however, the last suggested solution will be a problem if class name would be `0`, see https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#blessed

Comment: @vanHoesel: If you use "0" as a class name, then you deserve everything you get :-)

Comment: I think I just stumbled on a issue in the docs for `UNIVERSAL` where it does show the bad example code for `isa`. Luckily in `Scalar::Util` is is explained correctly: `defined blessed($thing) and $thing->isa(TYPE)`